# Cocos2dx- Display same image in multiple sizes

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

What is the best approach to display a same image multiple times e.g. 1000-2000 times? The image has to be rendered in discrete sizes across the screen. The most straight forward idea seems to be declaring different sprites for each image, but there should be a better approach?

Comment: 2000 sprites all at once? Way too many for current mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a lot !  I would create a batch node with the texture, and add to the batch node 999-1999 additional CCSprites that would be scaled and positioned where you want them. Then add the batch node to the scene and position it.

Then i would test that on the slowest-most-memory-limited device you intend to support with your app. I've gone up to 500 or so replicas like this (remember, only one draw call with a batch node).  I dont have a good 'feel' for your use case. In my case, the texture is small.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out! I was wondering if instead of textures I use primitives like polygons, is it an intelligent choice to draw this many primitives? My textures are have no fancy designs..so I can work with primitives as well. Any idea on this?